# .with alternative in scala

Tags: scala

I come from Groovy and it has a `.with` method on every type which accepts a single-argument closure; the argument is the object on which the `.with` method is being called. This allows a very cool technique of extending the functional chaining capabilities, which releases you from obligation to introduce temporary variables, factors your code, makes it easier to read and does other niceties.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
  .with(it => if (!it.isEmpty) println(it))
```

Instead of

```
val yetAnotherMeaninglessNameForTemporaryVariable = 
  Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
if (!yetAnotherMeaninglessNameForTemporaryVariable.isEmpty) 
  println(yetAnotherMeaninglessNameForTemporaryVariable)
```

In other words in the first example the `.with` is kinda similar to `.foreach` but instead of iterating thru the items of the object it is being called once on the object itself. So `it` is equal to `Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0)`.

Since I was very surprised not to find anything like that in Scala, my questions are:

- am I missing something?
- are there any alternative techniques native to Scala?
- if not, are there any decent reasons why this feature is not implemented in Scala?

**Update:** 
An appropriate feature request has been posted on the Scala issue tracker: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5324. Please vote and promote

Comment: Just a note: `with` is a reserved word in Scala, so the method could not be named the same thing.  It still should exist under some other name; this is _the most common Scala question and answer_ on StackOverflow as far as I can tell ("it doesn't exist; make your own like this")!

Comment: I think the name `convert` would fit best, thus suggesting that this method should have no side effects and since it takes the caller as a parameter and returns something new it must be some sort of conversion. In that sense this function would be irreplaceable in the standard library. Also as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8538277/485115 there also should be a side-effecting variant named `tap`, which returns the caller object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There doesn't exist any such method in the standard library, but it's not hard to define your own.

```
implicit def aW[A](a: A) = new AW(a)
class AW[A](a: A) {
  def tap[U](f: A => U): A = {
    f(a)
    a
  }
}

val seq = Seq(2, 3, 11).
          map(_ * 3).tap(x => println("After mapping: " + x)).
          filter(_ % 2 != 0).tap(x => println("After filtering: " + x))
```

**EDIT:** (in response to the comment)

Oh, I misunderstood. What you need is there in the Scalaz library. It comes under name `|>` (referred to as pipe operator). With that, your example would look like shown below:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0) |> { it => if(!it.isEmpty) println(it) }
```

If you cannot use Scalaz, you can define the operator on your own:

```
implicit def aW[A](a: A) = new AW(a)
class AW[A](a: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
}
```

And it's not a bad practice to pimp useful method(s) on existing types. You should use implicit conversions sparingly, but I think these two combinators are common enough for their pimps to be justifiable.

Comment: Yes I know that I can extend the standard library with implicits, but I just find stepping away from standards a bad practice. That's why my question was why don't Scala guys implement this, because probably this should be posted on their issue-tracker.

Besides your `tap` function although very useful is a bit different from `with` in sense that instead of result of the closure it returns the object itself. 

It would be very cool to have both `.with` and `.tap` in standard library IMO.

Comment: I name the same method `effect`.  Why `tap`?  I like that it's shorter, but I'm missing the mnemonic benefit.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Odersky criticized the habit of some Scala programmers of avoiding intermediate `val` declarations at all costs, which `|>` certainly contributes to, when the pipe operator was asked for. So, for now, I don't believe it will become part of the standard library.

Comment: @RexKerr: The name comes from Ruby, and I like it a lot. Short and sweet. I do not know the origin, but I am guessing it might have to do something with wiretapping.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Could you please provide a link? I want to his arguments

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/aI81VLgk_Gc/u6SGui4DEocJ). The whole thread is an interesting read.

Comment: I've read Martin's comments and I have to say that he made no worthy argument on that point. I mean of course you can ruin anything if you abuse it, but I also know from personal experience that this feature could be of extreme use if used properly. The only result of restraining this feature would be people making their own implicit extensions - well, as we see it already is. Also I want to say that I dislike the operator style name `|>` - the verbal `tap` and some alternative to `with` are much better IMO. So, guys, where should we post this feature request so we could all vote for that?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov - I personally use `use` for "with" and `effect` for `tap`, but if the community comes to some consensus, I'll switch.  It annoys me that there is not consensus, and I also dislike `|>` as the only option; it's good for point-free style, but hard to parse visually with dots.

Comment: It bothers me to see `|>` repeatedly being mentioned in context of point-free programming. It is a function _application_ operator, and has nothing to do with function _composition_ and hence point-free programming.

Comment: @RexKerr: Why `use`? I don't get the intuition for that name. (Nor for `effect` to be honest.)

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: I agree with you on that the argument Martin provided in that thread is not convincing. I personally find `|>` extremely useful, and I use it quite a lot. Regarding verbal name for that operation, how about `pipe` or `pipeTo`? That's how F#'ers read it (the language where it is used profusely), and also it is in essence same as UNIX pipes.

Comment: @missingfaktor I think the name `convert` would fit best, suggesting that this method should have no side effects and since it takes the caller as a parameter and returns something new it must be some sort of conversion. Anyway a much better place for that kind of discussion will be the issue on their tracker. I'm gonna look for their issue tracker today and post the issue and then post back with the link here.

Comment: Posted a feature request: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5324. Please vote and promote

Comment: I use `effect` because the whole point is to cause side-effects.  If you're not causing side-effects, the method is useless.  However, since `tap` is shorter, and you can think of tapping into an existing computation, I'll probably switch.  I use `use` mostly because it's short; you do want to use the argument in some way, but it does miss the transformative aspect of it.  Maybe just plain old `ap` (or `app`) is the way to go; I'd been avoiding `ap` to avoid conflicting with Scalaz, but I rarely use Scalaz.

Answer (score 7):

There is some syntax for this pattern included in Scala:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0) match { case it => if (!it.isEmpty) println(it) }
```

However, this is no accepted idiom so you should maybe refrain from (ab)using it.

If you dislike inventing loads and loads of names for dummy variables, remember that you can use scope braces:

```
val importantResult = {
  val it = Seq(1,2,3).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
  if (!it.isEmpty) println(it)
  it
}

val otherImportantResultWithASpeakingVariableName = {
  val it = // ...
  /* ... */
  it
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion on the match! Although a bit rough, it does answer first 2 of my questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try sth like this.

```
println(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0).ensuring(!_.isEmpty))
```

Throws an assertion exception if the condition is not met.

Comment: +1, although it will only work for single statement executions (e.g. println as cited here). if you wanted to do more than one operation, it will get tricky.

Comment: Nice technique for other purposes. For this one throwing an exception is overkill

Answer (score 1):

Remember call by name? Perhaps it gives you the capablity you want:

```
object Test {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   delayed(time());
 }

 def time() = {
    println("Getting time in nano seconds")
    System.nanoTime
 }

 def delayed( t: => Long ) = {
   println("In delayed method")
   println("Param: " + t)
   t
 }
}
```

as described in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/functions_call_by_name.htm

Answer (score 1):

Although I like other solutions better (as they are more local and therefore easier to follow), do not forget that you can

```
{ val x = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).filter(_ % 2 == 0); println(x); x }
```

to avoid name collisions on your meaningless variables and keep them constrained to the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is just function application `f(x)` flipped on its head: `x.with(f)`...  If you're looking for an idiomatic way of doing `with` in Scala, un-flip it:

```
(it => if (!it.isEmpty) println(it)) (Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(_ % 2 == 0))
```

Similarly, if you want `x.with(f).with(g)`, just use `g(f(x))`...