# Multi-Assignment based on Collection

Tags: scala, collections, tuples

**Edit**

originally the question was "Collection to Tuple" as I assumed I needed a tuple in order to do variable multi-assignment. It turns out that one can do variable multi-assignment directly on collections.  Retitled the question accordingly.

**Original**
Have a simple Seq[String] derived from a regex that I would like to convert to a Tuple.

What's the most direct way to do so?

I currently have:

```
val(clazz, date) = captures match {
  case x: Seq[String] => (x(0), x(1))
}
```

Which is ok, but my routing layer has a bunch of regex matched routes that I'll be doing val(a,b,c) multi-assignment on (the capture group is always known since the route is not processed if regex does not match).  Would be nice to have a leaner solution than match { case.. => ..}

What's the shortest 1-liner to convert collections to tuples in Scala?

Comment: The main problem, to me, is that different tuples are of different type, so I don't know if you can have a function which returns tuples of different size. 
Moreover, in your example, you should always have an escape case in a `match` in order to avoid problems, you should also be attentive to the fact that the `Seq` can be of length `<2`.

Comment: You know you can match a `xs: List[String]` like so: `val a :: b :: c :: _ = xs` to get the first three elements of the list?

Comment: @Chris, the route is not matched unless the regex matches, so I always know the length of the collection.  Furthermore, the collection type is always of type string.  I could do "val(a,b) = (captures(0), captures(1))", but I'm looking something more generalized

Comment: @ziggystar, +1 did not know that, very direct solution ;-)

Comment: @ziggystar, +1. After seeing your suggestion, my answer feels kind of stupid.

Comment: @ziggystar, might as well make your comment an answer so I can accept it as "the" answer (provided somehow someone improves on your spot-on concision)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question but might solve the problem in a different way.

You know you can match a `xs: List[String]` like so:

```
val a :: b :: c :: _ = xs
```

This assigns the first three elements of the list to `a,b,c`? You can match other things like `Seq` in the declaration of a `val` just like inside a `case` statement.  Be sure you take care of matching errors:

[Catching MatchError at val initialisation with pattern matching in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908707/scala-pattern-matching-and-try-catch/8909789#8909789)

Comment: It is not "an" answer to the question, it is "the" answer to the question

Comment: @virtualeyes It does not convert a collection to a tuple. People who will later find this thread might look for a solution to that problem, which my answer doesn't solve.

Comment: retitled the question accordingly, tuples are not the only means to do multi-assignment

Answer (score 3):

You can make it slightly nicer using `|>` operator from Scalaz.

```
scala> val captures = Vector("Hello", "World")
captures: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[java.lang.String] = Vector(Hello, World)

scala> val (a, b) = captures |> { x => (x(0), x(1)) }
a: java.lang.String = Hello
b: java.lang.String = World
```

If you don't want to use Scalaz, you can define `|>` yourself as shown below:

```
scala> class AW[A](a: A) {
     |   def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
     | }
defined class AW

scala> implicit def aW[A](a: A): AW[A] = new AW(a)
aW: [A](a: A)AW[A]
```

**EDIT:**

Or, something like @ziggystar's suggestion:

```
scala> val Vector(a, b) = captures
a: java.lang.String = Hello
b: java.lang.String = World
```

You can make it more concise as shown below:

```
scala> val S = Seq
S: scala.collection.Seq.type = scala.collection.Seq$@157e63a

scala> val S(a, b) = captures
a: java.lang.String = Hello
b: java.lang.String = World
```

Comment: hmmm, could also do, "val(a,b) = captures match { case x => (x(0), x(1)) }", without any magic. Saving a few characters does not justify going all-in on FP, I fold to @ziggystar's simplicity in this case ;-)

Comment: not magic in the sense of Ruby or Groovy untraceable magic, but magic in terms of complexity/having-to-grok-intent. To drive in a nail (solve a problem), when possible use a hammer (built-in language feature), before reaching for the screwdriver (FP).

Comment: +1, yes, that is a much, much better solution to this particular problem.  Assume this requires Scalaz? New to Scala, to be honest FP approaches in the Tony Morris vein are utterly baffling to me at this point. At some point I'll see the FP light, but for now am focusing on Scala itself. Saying that, I hope 2.10 and reflection comes soon! Otherwise I'll have no choice but to dive into Scalaz in order to validate these reflection-less case classes.

Comment: @virtualeyes, I am tired of people tacking on "complex" label in all the wrong places. Before using that word, did you make an attempt to understand `|>`? It's just function application, but from right-to-left. In other words, `f(x)` = `x |> f`. Why that direction? Because it helps the type inferer. When using left-to-right direction, in this case, you would have to specify the function argument type. i.e. `val (a, b) = ((x: Vector[String]) => (x(0), x(1)))(captures)`.

Comment: @virtualeyes, the edit does not make use of any Scalaz stuff btw.

Comment: @virtualeyes, +1 for reflection facilities. Much needed.

Comment: Is AW an abbrevation for something? If so, for what? Is there a searchable name for the |> method?

Comment: @userunknown: A stands for type parameter `A`. W stands for wrapper. Sorry for such naming, but that's quick and dirty stuff.

Comment: @userunknown, `|>` has no verbal alias, if that's what you are asking. (Don't look at me. I am not the author of Scalaz. (Although I happen to like that name.)) You can use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) to search for symbolic names.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Hasn't it been used to cat commands like in a pipe? `val res = f (a) |> g (_) |> h (_)`? Wouldn't `pipe` be an option for a name to talk about it?

Comment: @userunknown, right on! :-) Check my comments under the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537992/with-alternative-in-scala/8538277).

Comment: @userunknown, also please vote for [this proposal](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5324) if you like the idea.

Answer (score 2):

As proposed by @ziggystar in comments you can do something like:

```
val (clazz, date) = { val a::b::_ = capture; (a, b)}
```

or

```
val (clazz, date) = (capture(0), capture(1))
```

If you verified the type of the list before it is OK, but take care of the length of the `Seq` because the code will run even if the list is of size 0 or 1.

Comment: Why wouldn't one just do `val clazz :: date :: _ = capture`?

Comment: More directly I would do as @ziggystar suggested, "val clazz :: date = captures" Again, the length and type of the collection are known, the route is not matched unless the regex itself matches

Comment: Totally, I missed it, sorry I didn't understand well @ziggystar suggestion, so I thought my solution would improve it but it does not. 
EDIT: my answer provides a tupple, now I remember why I wrote it :-)

Comment: I love it how everybody calls him "@"ziggystar :)

Comment: right, could manually do with captures(0), captures(1); prefer ziggystar's solution....

Comment: It's ok, it was just for other people having a similar problem. I'm glad you found the perfect solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is originally specifically about assigning the individual capturing groups in a regex, which already allow you to assign from them directly:

```
scala> val regex = """(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)""".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)

scala> val regex(a, b, c) = "29-1-2012"
d: String = 29
m: String = 1
y: String = 2012
```

obviously you can use these in a case as well:

```
scala> "29-1-2012" match { case regex(d, m, y) => (y, m, d) }
res16: (String, String, String) = (2012,1,29)
```

and then group these as required.

Comment: "captures" is the Seq holding the result of the regex.  I do not have access to the regex itself, framework (scalatra) handles that

Answer (score 0):

### Seqs to tuple

To perform multi-assignment from a `Seq`, what about the following?

```
val Seq(clazz, date) = captures
```

As you see, no need to restrict to `List`s; this code will throw a `MatchError` if the length does not match (in your case, that's good because it means that you made a mistake). You can then add

```
(clazz, date)
```

to recreate the tuple.

### Tuples from matches

However, Jed Wesley-Smith posted a solution which avoids this problem and solves the original question better. In particular, in your solution you have a Seq whose length is not specified, so if you make a mistake the compiler won't tell you; with tuples instead the compiler can help you (even if it can't check against the regexp).